# Problems building XLNT library for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, excel, cmake

I am having trouble building the XLNT (https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt) library in Visual Studio 2017, and I'm confused.  I downloaded the latest version of the library and the latest version of CMake.  When I ran the CMake gui, it couldn't find the libstudxml files.  A post said that those needed to be downloaded; so I downloaded that library (https://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/libstudxml/#download) and placed it in third-party/libstudxml.

Then I got errors that it couldn't find some .hxx files in libstudxml.  I found this article, https://discourse.cmake.org/t/cmake3-20-cant-generate-xint-package/2987, that said I needed to replace libstudxml in some paths in the libstudxml.build\CMakeLists.txt file with just xml.  Then it still couldn't find these three .hxx files (content.hxx, exception.hxx, and forward.hxx).  I looked in the libstudxml/xml folder (they were all there but extensionless).  I changed the CMakeLists.txt file to not have the .hxx extension and Cmake was able to generate.

When I went to compile it in Visual Studio (hitting Project in the Cmake GUI), I got errors that some files couldn't find the content.hxx file again and the builds failed.  I'm kind of running in circles.  To get cmake to generate, I had to remove the .hxx extensions, but then some files complain because they are looking for them.  I tried leaving the three files witout the extensions and removing the extensions from the CMakeLists.txt file, but then some of the files were looking for the files without the extension.  Leaving the files both with and without the extension was also a cluster.  I understand that C++ can handle extensionless header files, but the CMake file seems to want extension, but I don't think VS is happy with them.

Additionally, while I needed to change the folder name to be xml instead of libstudxml for CMake, various include files in the source code are still looking for libstudxml; so that doesn't work.

Any thoughts?

Thanks--

Al

Comment: Looking at the source code content.hxx should exist: [https://git.codesynthesis.com/cgit/libstudxml/libstudxml/tree/libstudxml](https://git.codesynthesis.com/cgit/libstudxml/libstudxml/tree/libstudxml) its right here in the source code: [https://git.codesynthesis.com/cgit/libstudxml/libstudxml/tree/libstudxml/content.hxx](https://git.codesynthesis.com/cgit/libstudxml/libstudxml/tree/libstudxml/content.hxx)

Comment: With that said you may want to install xlnt using Microsoft's vcpkg: [https://vcpkg.io/en/packages.html](https://vcpkg.io/en/packages.html)

Comment: Thank you.  I wonder why my downloaded zip is extensionless...  That said, I'll take a look at using vcpkg as it should make life easier.

Comment: I have not tested this library specifically but can tell you that vcpkg can be helpful for third party libraries with complex dependencies. You want to start here; [https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg)

Comment: That did the trick.  Worked like a charm.  This page is also a good intro:  https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html.  After installed, I grabbed an xlnt example from their docs, and it compiled and ran fine.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problems with the same progress and blockages. Indeed changing the extensions or locations did not solve the problem. Then I tried to find another version of the libstudxml library, the creator of xlnt might have used an other one.

So I found the following archive: https://pkg.cppget.org/1/beta/libstudxml/
and placed the files in \xlnt-master\third-party\libstudxml , without modifying the names of the CMake path. This time I was able to compile the library (mingw32-make, I'm not using VS17 in my case).